$\cal{O}(n^k)$ complete algorithm for each natural $k$
I would like to exhibit a class of problems yes/no-one for each natural number $k$- for which there is an algorithm deciding the membership running in $\cal{O}(n^k)$ but for no $\epsilon>0$ in $\cal{O}(n^{k-\epsilon})$.

Have a look at the proof of the time hierarchy theorem.

@JeanAbouSamra Thank you for your hint. I'm aware of that theorem but at the same time I was unable to locate a concrete yes/no problem in that wikipedia article. Can you please be more exact where can I find it in that proof ?
